# ¿A qué se debe el error "The field X must be an accumulator object"?

Tags: mongodb

Con esta consulta quiero sacar los nodos precio y denominación de todos los productos:

```
db.producto.aggregate(
{$group:{_id:"$cod_prod","precio":"$precio","denominacion":"$denominacion"}}
)
```

Sin embargo, al ejecutarla me da el error:

> "errmsg" : "The field 'precio' must be an accumulator object"

¿Alguien sabe cómo corregirlo?

Answer (score 2):

Los campos que no son el _id , es necesario que lleven un acumulador, es decir, que sean computados.

```
{ $group: { _id: <expression>, <field1>: { <accumulator1> : <expression1> }, ... } }
```

Si no, puedes ponerlo en el _id  creando un objeto y sacarlos luego mediante un $project

Answer (score 1):

Si lo único que quieres es que sólo te muestre los valores para id, precio y denominación, lo que deberías usar es [project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/), no [group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/)